# n-spherical geometry

Tags: spherical-geometry

I'm interested in spherical geometry on the n-sphere.  Surely this has been done, but I can't find anything online.   Where? No luck with n-spherical geometry, hyperspherical geometry, or higher dimensional spherical geometry.

Comment: I don't know this subject, but the phrase "spherical spaces" might be worth searching with. For example, Leonard M. Blumenthal's 1935 paper [*Concerning spherical spaces*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2372018) seems somewhat relevant, at least the first page of it (this is all that I have access to).

Answer (score 1):

The correct term, for reasons I don't really understand, is [elliptic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_geometry).

Comment: Because the sectional curvature is +1 as opposed to -1 in the case of hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: Although typically elliptic geometry refers more to geometry in $\Bbb RP^n$ than in $S^n$.

Comment: @studiosus: but why is that "elliptic" and not "spherical"?

Comment: Because it also allows elliptic projective geometry.

Comment: @studiosus: right, and "hyperbolic geometry" also allows the geometry of hyperbolic manifolds not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{H}^n$. I'm not really asking for an answer to this question, just trying to communicate the source of my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try Volume 2 of M.Berger, "Geometry", chapters 18, 19.